# How to slice an object while push method

Tags: javascript, google-datalayer

I'm trying to slice `input[i].id` which looks like `1012410001` to `101241` (`slice(0,6)`). Is it possible to slice it with the `push` method or should it be done before?

```
function() {
    var input = {{dataLayer - purchase_products}};
    var products_list = [];
    for(i=0;i<input.length;i++){
        products_list.push({
            id: input[i].id,
            price: input[i].price,
            quantity: input[i].quantity
        });
    }
    return products_list;
}

dataLayer - purchase_products = [ { quantity: 1, coupon: [], name: 'Lancôme La vie est belle Eau de Parfum', id: '1012410001', price: 41.9, brand: 'Lancôme', category: 'Eau de Parfum', variant: null } ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can do that within the push.

You can also do a map (Assuming you're using ES6):

```
function() {
    var input = {{dataLayer - purchase_products}};
    var products_list = input.map((item) => {
        id: item.id.slice(0,6),
        price: item.price,
        quantity: item.quantity
    });
    return products_list;
}
```

Comment: quite the assumption :D haha just kidding!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why not:

```
products_list.push({
        id: input[i].id.slice(0,6),
        price: input[i].price,
        quantity: input[i].quantity
});
```